# C++ Prepocessing Directive

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

Let's say I have the following code

```
int i;
int j;
string s;
string t;
```

Is there any preprocessers that can convert it to something like this?

```
int i;
int j;
string s;
string t;
void print() {
    cout << i;
    cout << j;
    cout << s;
    cout << t;
}
```

Something that looked like this would be great.

```
#section print
int i;
int j;
string s;
string t;
#endsection
```

With the above code I would have to write another preprocessor that handles it but I do not know how.

Comment: I don't think that would be great. Rather a case of advanced code obfuscation. Could it be that you are just looking for a C++ *debugger*?

Comment: Well the code I am showing is not actually what I want to do, but very similar and it is a case of me being lazy. :)

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be that hard to have a macro that you can call like `FORM_PRINT(int, i, int, j, string, s, string, t);` (or some Boost PP sequence one), but I don't support that macro in any way.

Comment: Consider using a function template instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

Preprocessor-directives are defined in preprocessor, and You can not add new ones.

But You can easily write some script that would make such changes. (Per/Python/Ruby, whatever)

Only minus would be need for manually running that script before each compilation.

Comment: Using make or any similar build tool would make it simple to run the script automatically.

Comment: Do Yourself a favour and use different markup then preprocessor too. Cause other developers (You included AFTER some time), will not expect such behavior. New syntax will start them thinking.

Answer (score 3):

This is hardly what I'd call "great style" but a technique I use in a pinch, especially in restricted systems, called [XMacro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)

Basically, make a file with an extension like `.xmacro` (I will use `MyXMacro.xmacro`) then fill it with data like this:

```
XMACRO_INT(i)
XMACRO_INT(j)
XMACRO_STRING(s)
XMACRO_STRING(t)
#undef XMACRO_INT
#undef XMACRO_STRING
```

Then in your code you write something like this:

```
#define XMACRO_INT(x) int x ;
#define XMACRO_STRING(x) std::string x ;
#include "MyXMacro.xmacro"

void print() {
# define XMACRO_INT(x) std::cout << x ;
# define XMACRO_STRING(x) std::cout << x ;
# include "MyXMacro.xmacro"
}
```

At a certain point though, writing a script and incorporating it into your build is a better choice.

Comment: Wow - used this technique for years, but I never knew it had a name.

Comment: The sentiment "ugh." comes to mind. While on reading it appears that what you're suggesting should work as advertised, I certainly would not want to read someone else's code to understand what this convolution is doing, versus simply writing out the code.

Comment: @SteveFallows I recently stumbled upon it in an article and had the same revelation!

Comment: @mah For very large amounts of data in restrictive systems, this technique is very good.  I'm mostly talking about embedded platforms where the build chain is already complex and you're limited in language tools to achieve the same goal.  I agree though, I don't like it, but there's not really an equivalent.  And I'd much rather preach Don't Repeat Yourself than C Macros Are Ugly.

Comment: Yeah, I really only used this in my old embedded C days. Almost never in C++/templates era.

Comment: this is really cool but requires me to write more code than i would like to